# Inserting matrix as an element of matrix in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have the following matrix

`A=[11 23 32 12; 18 54 63 14; 43 32 13 65; 23 64 53 14; 65 54 63 72]`

The given matrix is a 5x4 matrix. I want to create 5x1 matrix, where each element is a matrix of 4x1. For example, `[11 23 32 12]` are to be kept in a matrix which is the first element of newly created 5x1 matrix.

I have tried this:

```
Y_new_cell=mat2cell(Y_new_cov1,[4 1],[1 10]);
```

but it is showing the following error:
`Input arguments, D1 through D2, must sum to each dimension of the input matrix size, [10 4].'`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The pedestrian way is this:

```
Y={A(1,:); A(2,:); A(3,:); A(4,:); A(5,:)}
```

Another way would be to use [`arrayfun`](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/arrayfun.html):

```
Y = arrayfun(@(ri) A(ri, :), 1:5, 'UniformOutput', 0)
```

This applies the row indexing to each element of the vector `1:5` and returns the result as a cell.

Or, if you want to use `mat2cell`, use the `rowdist` way of calling:

```
Y = mat2cell(A, ones(5,1));
```